# onbeforeunload custom dialog message not working

Tags: javascript, html, browser

i have a scenario where i need to show a dialog box asking user to recheck the changes that they have made

so for that i am doing onbeforeunload and want to get a message saying "Please recheck the rating and feedback that you have provided"

```
$window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        var dialogText = 'Please recheck the rating and feedback that you have provided';
        return dialogText;
    };
```

But this end up showing "Changes you made may not be saved"(default message).

I dont understand why i am getting as such

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function(e){
  // Show message
});
```

Comment: in return statement?

Answer (score 0):

See MSDN doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload

> WebKit-based browsers don't follow the spec for the dialog box.

You should try something like that:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
  var confirmationMessage = "Please recheck the rating and feedback that you have provided";
  e.returnValue = confirmationMessage;     // Gecko, Trident, Chrome 34+
  return confirmationMessage;              // Gecko, WebKit, Chrome <34
});
```

Comment: what browser are you testing with ?

Comment: I am testing with chrome

Comment: The string provided by the function will no longer be shown in the dialog. Rather, a generic string not under the control of the webpage will be shown. [https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5349061406228480] Chrome for desktop release 51

Comment: The message shown to the user is not customizable, but instead determined by the user agent. In particular, the actual value of the returnValue attribute is ignored. [https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#unloading-documents]

Comment: So you won't be able to display a custom message in recent browser, only the default one.